# Capture change event from multiple select and send state of all via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send an ajax request when any select inputs in a form have changed. If any of them change I want to send the current value of all the select inputs.

Currently I have the below which works for a single select input change,

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#id_fixed_or_variable').change(function (e) {
        var fixed = $(this).val()
        var filters = [fixed]
        console.log(fixed)
        $.ajax({
          url: '/users/quotes_results_filter/',
          data: {
            'filters': filters
          },
          success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
            $('.quotes').html(data)
          }
        })
      })
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an unique class for all your select and parse this.

**Example 1:** each select found is send with ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.variable-class').change(function (e) {
        $.each($('.variable-class'),function(i,e){
            var fixed = $(this).val()
            var filters = [fixed]
            console.log(fixed)
            $.ajax({
              url: '/users/quotes_results_filter/',
              data: {
                'filters': filters
              },
              success: function (data) {
                console.log(data)
                $('.quotes').html(data)
              }
            })
        })
    })
})
```

**Example 2** Create an object, push in it all select value and after send just one ajax request:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.variable-class').change(function (e) {
        var filters = {};
        $.each($('.variable-class'),function(i,e){
            var fixed = $(this).val()
            filters.push([fixed])
            console.log(fixed)
        })
        $.ajax({
          url: '/users/quotes_results_filter/',
          data: {
            'filters': filters
          },
          success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
            $('.quotes').html(data)
          }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks 2nd version was what I was looking for.  However no values appear unfortunately.  the `console/log(fixed)` doesn't output anything but if I do `console.log(e)` outside of the each function then each select change does output the event to the console.   (is it a `this` issue?) Also I made filters an array rather than an object.  (I'm trying to send a single ajax request with an array of all the select values - sorry I don't think I was specific enough above)

Comment: Got it the issue was the css class was in the parent element not the select.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there's plenty of solutions to that and probably cleaner than mine, but if I'm not wrong what you want to do can be solved using a class instead of an identifier. Something like this (not doing the ajax call)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.changeable').change(function(e) {
    console.log(getValues())
  })
})

function getValues() {
  var filters = [];
  $('.changeable').each(function() {
    filters.push($(this).val());
  });
  return filters;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="first" class="changeable">
  <option value="FirstOfFirst">First of First</option>
  <option value="SecondOfFirst">Second of First</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
<select id="second" class="changeable">
  <option value="FirstOfSecond">First of Second</option>
  <option value="SecondOfSecond">Second of Second</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
```